# C++ Use exported definitions inside shared library as inline

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is an easy way to use definitions as inline inside a shared library, but still export symbols for other application to import.

Comment: Provide a wrapper function for the API of the shared library that calls the inline function?

Comment: Is there a way without making a wrapper function?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you're talking about the `inline` keyword, then first of all remember that it's really only a *hint* that the compiler is allowed to inline the function (it might inline functions that are *not* marked as `inline` as well). Besides that all `inline` functions with external linkage (i.e. they're not `static` or put into an (non-inline) anonymous namespace) have to be defined as any other external linkage function and therefore could be called from external "modules".

Comment: Considering the comment above this, I think in most cases this will be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was hoping for a solution that would be something like telling the compiler to use my library functions inlined in the library assembly, but still make an export symbol. The library would then not need to call the actually function as it would be inlined and therefor there would be no double definitions.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you have? What is the reason behind this question? Do you have problems with "double definitions" right now? Please add a new question about the actual problem you have instead, describing any errors you have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm trying to keep out other library header files of my library header files, but still be able to inline my library functions in the library.

Comment: It is pretty much clear what you *want*. You are not saying what you *have* right now.

Comment: @n.m. What context are you referring to right now? What problem I have, or what code I have?

Comment: "What problem I have, or what code I have?" Both of course.

Comment: @n.m. I wrote what "problem" I have in my previous comment to Some programmer dude, and my code is irrelevant for my question.

Comment: I don't see error messages or any other undesired result mentioned anywhere in your comments, so I have no idea what problem you are talking about.

Comment: Nevermind, I've got your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the letter of the standard this is not possible.

> [dcl.inline]
>   6. An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case [...] If a function or variable with external linkage is declared inline in one translation
>   unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.

So the same function cannot be inline in a part of a program and non-inline in another part. You have to use a wrapper.

gcc has a way to export `inline` functions. Try `-fkeep-inline-functions` or `__attribute__((used))`. It isn't clear how useful this is in the context of C++, as according to the rules you have to export inline function definitions for all to see, and then they will be inlined by the client of your shared library. Clang only supports `__attribute__((used))`.

If you are willing to play lose with the standard, you can try to ignore either of the two quoted sentences and hope for the best. I have tried both methods with gcc and they both appear to work, however they both result in undefined behaviour, so no guarantees.

1. An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used --- ignore this. Just don't define it when you are not compiling the library. Mark it with `__attribute__((used))` so that the symbol is emitted.

   ```
   class X {
      inline void foo();
   };

   #ifdef BUILDING_SHARED_LIB
      void __attribute__((used)) X::foo() {}
   #endif
   ```
2. it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears --- ignore this. Just don''t declare it `inline` (and of course don't define it) when you are not compiling the library. Mark it with `__attribute__((used))` so that the symbol is emitted.

   ```
   class X {
      void foo();
   };

   #ifdef BUILDING_SHARED_LIB
      inline void __attribute__((used)) X::foo() {}
   #endif
   ```

Both methods appear to work for me, however as I've said no guarantees can be given as this is UB according to the standard. The Itanium ABI however doesn't care if a function is declared inline or not, so one can possibly regard the ABI as giving the guarantee in case 2. I cannot vouch for this.

Comment: Thanks alot! This was what I had in mind. I will have to test this and think about if it's worth implementing. Do you know if MSVC has implemented any feature like `-fkeep-inline-functions`?

Comment: @PeterBechP haven't checked it but adding the normal dllexport to an inline function should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper for export:

```
// public header
MY_DLL_INTERFACE void foo(void);

// private header
inline void foo_impl(void) { … }

// impl
void foo(void) { foo_impl(); }
```